# Formatting string in scala

Tags: scala

I have json string like this:

```
str = {"id" : %s, "name": %s}
```

I want to replace format specifier %s with values. I have array that contains values to be replaced.

I am able to do this using

```
str.format(arrayofvalue: _*)
```

but this works only for one specific type format identifier.

what in case if i have string with multiple format specifier like (%d, %s)

```
str = {"id" : %d, "name": %s}
```

above solution does not work in this case (illegalFormatConversion). Is there any function/ work around to handle this.

Comment: Could you post the whole exception message?

Comment: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

Comment: See the answers, if you still have trouble, you should also post how you initialize `arrayofvalue`.

Answer (score 1):

you get this exception if the types are not compatible.

```
 val str = "{\"id\" : %d, \"name\": %s}"
 val arrayofvalue = Array("1", "a")
 val output = str.format(arrayofvalue: _*)
 println(output)    
 // will result in java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
```

But if you provide compatible types it will work:

```
 val str = "{\"id\" : %d, \"name\": %s}"
 val arrayofvalue = Array(1, "a")
 val output = str.format(arrayofvalue: _*)
 println(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.format(arrayofvalue: _*)` works. Your problem is that you pass in the incorrect type in your array, or have the order of values in the array wrong.

You can verify it works with this example:

```
val str = """{"id" : %d, "name": %s}"""
val arrayOfValue = Array(1, "John")
str.format(arrayOfValue: _*) // returns: {"id" : 1, "name": John}
```

Now if I changed `arrayOfValue` to

```
val arrayOfValue = Array("1", "John")
```

(notice that argument `"1"` is now not an Int but a String), you get the exception `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String`.